# Display data into dropdown list from database using php

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

Here i am trying to fetch data from database and display it into dropdown list using PHP. Though there is data available into table it will not display it into dropdown list.what is the problem behind that and what is the solution for that???

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
       include 'footer.php';
        include './config.php';
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="page-wrapper">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <h1 class="page-header">Add Product</h1>
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Product
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <form action="AddProduct.php" method="POST" role="form">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Project Name</label>
                                        <?php 
                                            $sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";
                                            echo "<select class='form-control' name='project'>";
                                            echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
                                            foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                                            echo "<option value=$row[Project_id]>$row[Project_title]</option>";  
                                            }
                                            echo "</select>";

                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Product Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="Product_name" type="text" id="Product_name" required="required" title="Enter Product Name">

                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit Query</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Particular Circle Will be included for selected Project</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Do you want to proceed??
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>   
                </div> 


</body>
```

Page sources:

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Test Management Tool</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

    <link href="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="../../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top"  role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="DeshbordAdmin.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Administrator</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">

                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">

                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="../../logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>  
        </nav>
    </div>
    <script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js">    </script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="../../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>

    <!-- Page-Level Demo Scripts - Notifications - Use for reference -->
    <script>
    // tooltip demo
    $('.tooltip-demo').tooltip({
        selector: "[data-toggle=tooltip]",
        container: "body"
    })

    // popover demo
    $("[data-toggle=popover]")
        .popover()
    </script>
    </body>
</html><!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Test Management Tool</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->

<link href="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="../../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Navigation -->

        <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
            <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                    <li class="sidebar-search">
                        <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="DeshbordAdmin.php"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i> User<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="AddUser.php">Add User</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Delete User</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Project<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="AddProject.php">Add Project</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">View Project</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Product<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="AddProduct.php">Add Product</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">Assign Product</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="morris.html">View Product</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-fw"></i>Test Suites<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Add Test Suite</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Delete Test Suite</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Update Test Suite <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                                <ul class="nav nav-third-level">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Add Test case</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Delete Test case</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                                <!-- /.nav-third-level -->
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> Test Case<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="panels-wells.html">Add Test Case</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="buttons.html">Update Test Case</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="notifications.html">View Test Case</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="tables.html"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch"></i> Circe</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="forms.html"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-files-o fa-fw"></i> Reports<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                            <li>
                                <a href="blank.html">Blank Page</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="login.html">Login Page</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
</div>
<!-- /#wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="page-wrapper">
       <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12">
               <h1 class="page-header">Add Product</h1>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Product
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                        <form action="AddProduct.php" method="POST" role="form">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Project Name</label>
                                    <select class='form-control' name='project'><option value=''>Select One</option><option value=''></option>    <option value=''></option><option value=''></option><option value=''></option><option value=''></option></select>                                    </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Product Name</label>
                                    <input class="form-control" name="Product_name" type="text" id="Product_name" required="required" title="Enter Product Name">

                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit Query</button>
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                </div>

                                <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Particular Circle Will be included for selected Project</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    Do you want to proceed??
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Save changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-content -->
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                    </div>

                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                </div>   
            </div> 


</body>
```

Comment: Whats the result you got with the above code?

Comment: I am not getting anything means it will not show me the data into dropdown list..

Comment: In your DB abstraction layer, does `$conn->query($sqll);` actually return the result set? If this is using PDO, does $conn->errorInfo() return anything?

Comment: yes it will return result set.and $conn->errorInfo() is not return anything

Comment: Can you view page source in your browser and post the resulting HTML that is appearing?

Comment: Yes, i will give you...

Comment: @TrilokPatel did you try my code below?

Comment: yes but not working @Phuti

Comment: @TrilokPatel show us how you connect to your database, the code is working on my site that can only mean one thing you are not connecting to the database correctly.

Comment: <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '', 'tmtool');
                            if($conn -> connect_errno){
                                die('coudn\'t connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
                            }
?>
 i am using netbeans and in that i have use this code to connect to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the problem is that you are missing single qoutes in your echo `$row[project_id]` which should be `$row['project_id']`.
what happens if you change your code to the following?

```
<?php 
    $sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";
    echo "<select class='form-control' name='project'>";
    echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>"; 
    $results =  $conn->query($sqll);
    foreach ($results as $row) {
        echo "<option value=$row[Project_id]>$row[Project_title]</option>";  
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: @TrilokPatel is this `PDO` ?

Comment: the code is working well on my site, maybe there are no entries in your database.

Comment: thats the main problem. there is entry available in my db though it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<html>
    <?php
        include 'header.php';
       include 'footer.php';
        include './config.php';
    ?>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="page-wrapper">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-12">
                   <h1 class="page-header">Add Product</h1>
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        Product
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <form action="AddProduct.php" method="POST" role="form">
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Project Name</label>
                                        <?php 
                                            $sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";
                                            echo "<select class='form-control' name='project'>";
                                            echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
                                            foreach ($conn->query($sqll) as $row){
                                            echo "<option value=".$row['Project_id'].">".$row['Project_title']."</option>";  
                                            }
                                            echo "</select>";

                                        ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Product Name</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" name="Product_name" type="text" id="Product_name" required="required" title="Enter Product Name">

                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Submit Query</button>
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Particular Circle Will be included for selected Project</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        Do you want to proceed??
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit">Save changes</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- /.modal-content -->
                            </div>
                            <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
                        </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>   
                </div> 


</body>
```

Comment: Please check the source code. and search for name='project'. What it returns in the select box section? Also check the field names. Is this the field names Project_id and Project_title?

Comment: Field name is correct and these both(old & new ) code are run in another machine succesfully means it will show the name into dropdown list but not in my machine?????

Comment: `echo "<option value='".$row['Project_id']."'>".$row['Project_title']."</option>";` Replace this code and check. If you are still facing the same issue, then let me know, is there any quote in your title? like John's

Comment: No this is your original code. Please share the page source code. Run the page and get from browser and send.

Comment: No Trilok, You need to run the web page in browser and right click on the browser. Now you will get options. In that, click "View page source". Now you will get new tab with page source. Copy that and share. Currently you have shared the original code not page source.

Comment: Where you have updated? Same URL? But still I can see the original code not page source in that URL.

Comment: Also paste `echo '<pre>';print_r($conn->query($sqll));`  after `$sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";` and share the output.

Comment: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 5
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)                                 those are display with previous output..

Comment: Click  this [link](http://screencast.com/t/xGBCpdUMXP8) You can see the foreach is running fine but only the value is not getting display. The field name may be wrong or method used to display the value is wrong. Replace `echo "<option value=".$row['Project_id'].">".$row['Project_title']."</option>";` with `echo "<option value=".$row->Project_id.">".$row->Project_title."</option>";` and check. If you are still facing the same issue, as I asked early paste `echo '<pre>';print_r($conn->query($sqll));` after `$sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";` and share the output.

Comment: mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 5
    [lengths] => 
    [num_rows] => 2
    [type] => 0
)                           same as last one not working...And one another thing i want to remind you that all these code are succeessfully run in another pc.It will not run only in my pc!!!!

Comment: Replace this code and check. `$sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master";
$rows = $conn->query($sqll);
echo "<select class='form-control' name='project'>";
echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>";  
                                            foreach ($rows->fetch_assoc() as $row){
                                            echo "<option value=".$row['Project_id'].">".$row['Project_title']."</option>";  
                                            }
                                            echo "</select>";

                                        ?>`

Comment: It will display only first character of first row from database.means in my db value for first row is 123,Trilok then it will give me 1 and T in drop down list there is more then one row available and i want to display name of the project_ title instead of first character.

Comment: Replace `foreach ($rows->fetch_assoc() as $row){` with `while($row= $rows->fetch_assoc() ) {` and check.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Karthikeyani, I have
Replace this code

```
$sqll="SELECT * FROM project_master"; $rows = $conn->query($sqll);
 echo "<select class='form-control' name='project'>";
echo "<option value=''>Select One</option>"; 
while($rows->fetch_assoc() as $row){
    echo "<option value=".$row['Project_id'].">".$row['Project_title']."</option>"; 
} 
echo "</select>"; ?>
```